# cURL request by using cookies and cache from your current browser

Tags: curl, cookies, browser, user-agent

I have create an bash script with cURL for a website, but the script does not work because the website use an Facebook account to login. When I open my Firefox browser and visit the specific website I am already logged in.

If I could use the cURL script with my cache and cookies of my current Firefox browser it will probably work.
Is this possible?

Comment: you could try coding something similar with greasemonkey. then it will work, as it runs from within the browser

Comment: Does an unix batch script works in Greasemonkey?

Comment: no, but depending on your script it may be possible to create a bridge for these two using a local web server i guess

Comment: Mm this is not really the solution I am looking for, is there no way to use my cach and cookies from my Firefox browser?